# Word boundaries with extented set of characters

Tags: regex, word-boundaries

It seems a little strange to me that `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. I wonder why `0-9` and `_` are counted between word characters and why `-` is not counted between word characters.

If I want to split the sentence:

`This is counter-example.`

with `(\w*\b)` it will split the word *counter-example* to two parts. Similarly `(count.*?\b)` matches only `counter`.

Would it be possible to have something like `\b` with the result that `-` is included in word characters (`\w`)?

Or did I misunderstood the usage of `\b`? Are there some examples of standard usage of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `\w` matches the underscore along with uppercase and lowercase letters is historical: it is due to the fact that it was first introduced to match C identifiers.

Well, this is true for Java's `\w` (yes, `\w` will not match accentuated characters in Java).

`\b` however is an anchor, and it *is not* defined by the frontier between what is a word character and a non word character, in fact it is implementation-dependent.

There is not really an anchor which does what you want, but if you want to match words and dashes, your best bet is `\w*(-\w*)*`.

Again, the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern!

(and BTW, `\b` is a "word anchor" in some dialects only, other implementations define `\<` and `\>` instead for the beginning and end of word anchors respectively)

[edit for a gross error]

Comment: OK. I see that it's better to define my own sets with [...], but it would be great to see some useful usage of `\b` e.g. in C source code (what they did with it).

Comment: Any time you want to match a "word frontier" is useful -- use cases are many, you just haven't encountered one yet ;)

Comment: If you would encounter some use case, please paste here a link, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `[\w-]*`

For example you want to match something which ends with e and starts with co

String:

```
This is counter-example.
```

Regex:

```
co[\w-]*e
```

Match:

```
counter-example
```